# how to move a few letters between 'a' and 'z'

Tags: c

I have an exercise that I need to take a string, reverse it, and then I'm entering a number and each letter needs to be moved a few letters according to that number, and I need to use in all of that with pointers.
here is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LEN 100
void decryptText(char* encText, int n);
int main(void)
{
    char str[LEN] = { 0 }; 
    int num = 0; 
    printf("Please enter a string :\n");
    fgets(str, LEN, stdin);
    printf("\nPlease enter a number:\n");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    decryptText(str, num);
    getchar();
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

void decryptText(char* encText, int n)
{
    int i = 0, len = 0 , value = 0 ;
    char moved = ""; 

    for (i = 0; i<LEN; i++){
        if (*encText == '\0') 
        {
            break;
        }
        encText++;
    }
    len = i;
    encText--;
    printf("The secret message is: \n\n");
    for (i = len; i>0; i--)
    { 
        value = (int*)(encText--); 
        moved = (char)(value + n);
        *encText = moved; 
        printf("%c", *encText);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}
```

The program does not work, and I still need to make my letters only between 'a' and 'z' and I can't change the pointer to move the letter.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense.

Comment: __*ptr++__ will advance the pointer , while __(*ptr)++__ will increment the contents, changing "A" into "B" , for example.

Comment: Since you do not advance `encText`, the code `*encText = moved;` simply overwrites the first character in `encText` each iteration. You need to explain how you are trying to encode the string in `decryptText`, currently the code for `value`, `moved` and the assignment to `*encText` does not make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define LEN 100

void decryptText(char* encText, int n);

int main(void){
    char str[LEN] = { 0 }; 
    int num = 0; 
    printf("Please enter a string :\n");
    fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);
    str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = '\0';//remove newline
    printf("\nPlease enter a number:\n");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    num = num % 26;
    decryptText(str, num);
    //getchar();
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

void decryptText(char* encText, int n){
    int i = 0, len = 0 , value = 0 ;
    unsigned moved = '\0';

    for (i = 0; *encText; i++){
        ++encText;
    }
    len = i;
    --encText;

    printf("The secret message is: \n\n");
    for (i = len; i>0; i--){
        value = *encText;
        if(isupper(value))
            value = tolower(value);
        if(islower(value)){
            moved = value + n;
            if(moved > 'z')
                moved = 'a' -1 + moved - 'z';
            else if(moved < 'a')
                moved = 'z' +1 + moved - 'a';
            *encText = moved;
        }
        printf("%c", *encText--);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}
```